# Convert string to datetime in cosmos db

Tags: sql, datetime, azure-cosmosdb, date-conversion

In my cosmos db a date field is stored as string like this
{
"ValidationWeekStartDay": "27-Apr-2020"
}

I have to write a query to extract all documents whose ValidationWeekStartDay is greater than current date. How can I achieve this in cosmos db query?

**Select * from c wher c.ValidationWeekStartDay > GetCurrentDateTime ()**

this does not give me correct result.

Comment: What is the inconsistency in results you get? I tried with same query and it did work for me. Can you please post couple of documents too, would be easier to understand the real issue then?

Comment: I have below document
[
    {
        "stdDates": "13-Apr-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "20-Apr-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Apr-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "20-Jul-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Jul-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "03-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "10-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "17-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "10-Aug-2020"
    }
]

Comment: [
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Apr-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "20-Jul-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Jul-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "03-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "10-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "17-Aug-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "10-Aug-2020"
    }
]

if run query  select  c.stdDates as stdDates from c Where c.stdDates > GetCurrentDateTime ()
it gives me wrong result 

[
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Apr-2020"
    },
    {
        "stdDates": "27-Jul-2020"
    }
]

Comment: Was able to reproduce the issue with the data provided by you. Posted a way to handle the same in answers. Please let me know if that works with you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with date format, the documents you are storing is in format 'dd-MMM-yyyy' while GetCurrentDateTime() function gets the date in format 'yyyy-mm-dd....'. So when you run the above query, comparison like below happens:

```
'27-Apr-2020' > '2020-08-17'
```

It compares the characters one by one and first 2 characters of first value becomes greater than second value. For testing purpose, anything above date 20 will be returned by your query irrespective of any month.

There are 2 ways to resolve this.

1. Store the date in same format as GetCurrentDateTime() function.
2. Create a udf like below. You can create your own udf, this is just a sample one based on date format.(pardon the formatting, you can copy and run it as it is)

   `function formatdatetime(datetime){ datetime = datetime.substring(7,11) + '-' + datetime.substring(3,6) + '-' +  datetime.substring(0,2); datetime = datetime.replace('Jan','01'); datetime = datetime.replace('Feb','02'); datetime = datetime.replace('Mar','03'); datetime = datetime.replace('Apr','04'); datetime = datetime.replace('May','05'); datetime = datetime.replace('Jun','06'); datetime = datetime.replace('Jul','07'); datetime = datetime.replace('Aug','08'); datetime = datetime.replace('Sep','09'); datetime = datetime.replace('Oct','10'); datetime = datetime.replace('Nov','11'); datetime = datetime.replace('Dec','12'); return datetime; }`

And then use the below query:

`select c.stdDates as stdDates from c Where udf.formatdatetime(c.stdDates) > GetCurrentDateTime ()`